# Test connectivity to external ip from Azure Application Gateway ip address

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

A third party webservice has whitelisted the public static IP address of my Azure Application Gateway.

I would like to be able to ping/telnet to the IP address of the service from the IP address of my application gateway. Is this possible?

How can I test connectivity from my Application Gateway to that service?

Comment: If you have configured an app gateway in front of web service, you could check the `backend health` in the app gateway main page or check the diagnostic logs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-diagnostics

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to test connectivity from Azure Application Gateway. In App Service you get an option to KUDU console from where you can do TCPPing to test connectivity.

You need to work with your Third party web Service to try access Application Gateway and check the Access logs whether you got any request and response.